# how to format input text into equation using action script 2.0

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I am very new to action script, and using action script 2.0, I am having a problem getting an input textbox to read in mathematical formulas. To enter `5x^2`, the key sequence to be used is `{5}{x}{2}`. i.e., the characters must be formatted as it is being typed.

Ultimately, I want to enter equations like `5x^2-4x-2`.

The textbox should not allow non-numerical characters other than `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict an input text field to only take certain characters using TextField.restrict 
See the docs [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#restrict)

Comment: Hello, thankq for ur reply.iam not getting character comparsion.I embeded Characters "all numbers,x,+,-" in the properties dialog for my_txt(my text field instance).iam comparing the last char with x.if equal the next character should be a number & number should formated as a power of x.but the below code is not working.can u plz help me. 
my_txt.onChanged = function(textfield_txt:TextField) { 
var input:String=my_txt.text;
 if((input.substring((input.length)-1, input.length)=="x") 
{
 trace("ok");
 } }

Comment: It isn't clear to me exactly what you want. It looks like you are trying to input quadratic equations, but without knowing the value of (x) you can't apply Math functions to it. What I think you need to look into is String.indexof('x') which will return the position in the string of this character. If you do this on all the non-numerical characters then you should be able to determine the structure of the inputted string.